# log4j2.xml is not recognised by Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I am trying to create logs using the log4j-core Maven dependency in Spring Boot. When I try to use below code in application.properties, error logs are generated

application.properties :

```
# Set the logging level for Spring Framework to ERROR
logging.level.com.crystalbi.push_notifications = INFO

# Define the log file location and log pattern
logging.file.name = errorlogs/error-logs.log 
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
logging.pattern.file=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-file-size = 1GB
```

When I do the same with the XML file, it's not working.

My goal is to create two separate log files. One where I can store my error logs (in errorlogs folder) and my general logs (in generallogs folder). when I create a log4j2.xml file and try to run my server again to test the file, there are no logs stored in any of the folders. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

my Log4j2.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <!-- General Logs Appender -->
        <RollingFile name="GeneralLog" fileName="generalLogs/app.log" filePattern="generalLogs/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </RollingFile>
        
        <!-- Error Logs Appender -->
        <RollingFile name="ErrorLog" fileName="errorlogs/error.log" filePattern="errorlogs/error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            </Filters>
        </RollingFile>
        
        <Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.mkyong" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="GeneralLog"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.springframework.boot" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ErrorLog"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="ERROR">
            <AppenderRef ref="GeneralLog"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="ErrorLog"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

My Maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I expect to get the logs in their respective folders, but it won't work, and I don't know why. I am using Spring Boot 3.1.3. I am new to this logging concept and have never worked with this.

Comment: Spring Boot starters all depend upon [`spring-boot-starter-logging`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/3.1.4). Unless you exclude it (check `mvn dependency:tree`) you'll have Logback on your classpath. Spring Boot is configured to prefer Logback over Log4j Core.

Comment: Check also [Ralph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62915965/11748454).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using:

```
org.slf4j.Logger
```

Accordingly, the configuration file:

```
logback-spring.xml
```

Comment: hey thanks @Vasiliy , maybe log4j2 had this issue, just solved the issue using slf4j

Comment: For spring, a native logger - slf4j

Answer (score -1):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Try adding these 3 dependencies.

Create a variable in java file

```
private final Logger logRefInJava = LoggerFactory.getLogger("logRefInJava");
```

And then write a log using above variable

```
logRefInJava.info("This is an info log");
```

logback.xml in `main/resources`. You can create as many files as you want. Just different variables and accordingly give a reference  into logback.xml.

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="loggerName" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>logs/logFileName.json</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="logRefInJava" level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="loggerName" />
    </logger>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M\(%line\) - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Let me know how it goes and we can discuss further. Alternatively you can share your git repository where we can work on it.

Comment: Seems you have the answer

Comment: Hey Vinit, thanks for the solution. Yeah, the log4j2.xml file was not getting recognized by my spring-boot for some reason, then I removed the log4j dependency and used slf4j, and now it is working fine. Don't know what the issue was